# How much does a a cup of rice weigh?

Tags: rice, measurements

I use the cup that came with my rice cooker to measure the rice for each meal.

I often eat 120ml~160ml rice (before cooking) measured in the cup at a time. How much does that amount of rice weigh? (I don't have a scale). The purpose of the question is to plan how much rice to buy at a time..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on the rice. I have done my own measurements in the past (I hate volumetric measurements,) and found:

- 1 full-to-the-brim rice cooker cup of dry SunRice Brown rice (medium grain?) weighed 142g.
- 1 full-to-the-brim rice cooker cup of dry SunRice Calrose rice (medium grain) weighed 150g.

Both were Australian grown rice.

The rice cooker cup's top measurement is 160ml, but I always fill to the brim because ... I'm too lazy to look at the notch.

*Why is the weight different?*

Because different grains of rice can wedge together more efficiently (less air pockets.) The weight measurement for a long grain rice like Basmati would be different again.

**TL;DR:** buy a scale to be accurate.